# use executeScript to execute a function from popup.html

Tags: function, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

so, I'm trying to use **executeScript** to execute a function of **popup.html**.

That's what I'm trying to do:

```
function atacar () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#target_attack").click();
    });
}

function apoiar () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#target_support").click();
    });
}

function enviar_comando (tipo) {
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win) {
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs) {
            for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                if (tipo == "ataque") chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { code: "atacar();" });
                else if (tipo == "apoio") chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { code: "apoiar();" });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Look at those lines:

```
                if (tipo == "ataque") chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { code: "atacar();" });
                else if (tipo == "apoio") chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { code: "apoiar();" });
```

I'm trying to execute a function of **popup.html** that's called **atacar()** and **apoiar()**, but it's not working.

Help? :)

Comment: Please help by clarifying where each piece of code you've added appears (is it in popup.html? in the content script? etc.)

Comment: The whole code is in popup.html.

Answer (score 0):

Since atacar() and apoiar() are also in popup.html , you can't run them from the executeScript.
You can either:

- Insert these functions also into the code string that you're supplying to executeScript, or
- better yet, move these 2 functions into a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) and then you can run them like you do.